# [NSDictionary]!? is not convertible to [NSDictionary]?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am getting

> '[NSDictionary]!? is not convertible to [NSDictionary]?' error on following code.

```
  var jsonResult:[NSDictionary]! = [NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error1)] as? [NSDictionary]!
```

Why does that happen?

Comment: That's not Swift2 (see tag) ;-)

Comment: If it's the wrong tag you should suggest an edit and say why. It'll improve the question for those with the same problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: remove the `[` and `]` around the `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData`, if you put it in array it will get very hard to cast it.

Use the following

```
var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error1) as! NSDictionary
```

`as?` optionally casts to the given type. Therefore you end up with an optional of type `[NSDictionary]!` -> `[NSDictionary]!?` which is in fact not convertible to `[NSDictionary]!` but unwrapable. Which would not make sense to optinally cast and the unwrap, just use the unwrapping cast in the first place.

The [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID338) are really helpful in this case of situations regarding optionals!

A little bit more explanation on my first point: You were putting the returned value of `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` in an array, which will result in [AnyObject?] which is not really castable to [AnythingElse] since you have to unwrap the optionals before casting. I do not know of any built-in way of doing this. AND it did not make any sense in your scenario. You still can wrap the value in an array after all that castings, which you could do via

```
var jsonResult = [NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error1) as! NSDictionary]
```

Comment: now I am getting [AnyOBject?] is not convertible to [NSDictionary]

Comment: @MuhammadSaifullah I'm sorry, I fixed it I think. Your code confused me quite a bit - why were you using an Array?

Comment: for NSDictionary it is working fine. actually my api returns JsonArry and if i use NSDictionary convertion my json array is not serialized/converted to NSDictionary, that is why I tried to use arry

Comment: @MuhammadSaifullah An array of json objects is not valid json! I do not think that would actually be parseable. You have to wrap the multiple objects inside a container / array and print that as json and then continue along the normale way.

Comment: Thanks @luk2302 I got it now.